# Finding another taylor series

Tags: real-analysis

In the following question I am trying to find the Taylor series for,

$f(x)=e^x$

centered at $x=1$

So looking at the derivatives gives us the following,

$f(x)=e^x,f(1)=e$
$f'(x)=e^x,f'(1)=e$
$f''(x)=e^x,f''(1)=e$

Seeing this result how do I find the form $c_k=\frac{f^{k}(a)}{k!}$ to solve my problem?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Looking at the deratives I have found how do I use these to show the correct form for the taylor series?

Comment: Well, you appear to be able to figure out $f^k(a)$.  What's holding you back?

Comment: What is the definition of a Taylor series?

Comment: so $e^x=\sum \frac{e}{n!}$??

Comment: so $e^x=\sum \frac{e}{(x-1)^n}$??

Comment: $$e^x = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ implies $$e^{x-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}$$ and $$ e^{x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{e}{n!}(x-1)^n.$$

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio so $f(x)=e^x$ centered at $x=1$ is $e^x=\sum \frac{e}{n!}(x-1)^n$?

Comment: which one $e^x=\sum \frac{e}{n!}(x-1)^n$? or $\sum \frac{e}{(x-1)^n}$

Comment: @user905: you should start from the definition of *power series*. Equality has to hold at $x=1$, and for sure $\sum\frac{e}{0}\neq e.$

Answer (score 0):

From your work, you're on the right track. The series will be monotonically strictly increasing.
your series will be of the form;
f(x)=f(a)+(f'(a)/1!)(x-a)+(f''(a)/2!)((x-a)^2)+...
where your f^k(a)/k! will be constant (Euler number)